# In Rails, what could cause a user to have another user's session?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, apache, session, passenger

I have a Rails application using with an authentication system using Restful Authentication without any modification.

Users have reported finding themselves logged in as the wrong user. In at least one case it was on their very first page view, never having logged in before.

Is it possible their session ids are getting mixed up? Would switching to CookieStore make it impossible for this to happen since no session data is stored on the server this way?
I suspect the problem is related to Passenger but I don't know where to start debugging this. Its only happened about 4 times in several months of being live so its virtually impossible to reproduce.

Environment:
ActiveRecord session storage
Rails 2.2.2
Passenger 2.0.1
Apache 2
Ruby 1.8.6

Many thanks

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you use a client-side session storage (default for newer Rails versions), it may be a mistake in the application and not a stolen session (or something like that). Make sure that you know which session storage you use and how it works.

Comment: Not sure I follow the logic here... whether the session is serialized into a cookie (the current default) or an id is generated and it's dropped in the database, the only way someone's going to grab another one's session is if the server sends up the wrong cookie (be it a session id or a fully serialized session) the likelihood of which wouldn't depend on the storage medium.  But, perhaps I'm overlooking something here?

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing this too... you might be interested in the thread here: [Users take sessions of other users when sessions are stored in memcached (Rails)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524187/users-take-sessions-of-other-users-when-sessions-are-stored-in-memcached-rails)

My current thinking is that this is actually related to Passenger, that seems to be the common component between what you're seeing, what I'm seeing, and what the other post reports (we're all using different session stores and rails versions).

Answer (score 0):

I once experienced a similar problem and the cause turned out to be that the user was stored in a class variable instead of an instance variable. Say for instance that you authenticate/store your user like this:

```
  def current_user
    User.current ||= ( login_from_session || login_by_password )
  end
```

In this case the user will be stored in the class and not the instance and the first user who login will be stored in the class and that will be passed over to the next users session as well. To solve it, this was changed to

```
def current_user
  @current_user ||= ( login_from_session || login_by_password )
end
```

This is of course only one of many possibilities but I would start my troubleshooting by writing both the user_id from the session and the user variable you use, to the log to see if there are any differences.